# SQL Show COUNT with AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2012, average

I am trying to combine a `COUNT` that contains a `GROUP BY` with a `AVG` statement. I am using MSSql.

Is it possible to have the `AVG` next to the `COUNT` results?

**COUNT SQL:**

```
SELECT ActionId, COUNT(ActionId) as ActionCount
FROM AIFMESSAGELOG
WHERE DIRECTION = 1 AND CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000' AND CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000'
Group By ActionId
Order By ActionCount DESC
```

This returns:

```
ActionId       ActionCount
Insert Action  672
Update Action  184
```

**AVG SQL:**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, b.CREATEDDATETIME, a.CREATEDDATETIME)*1.0 AS AvgTime 
FROM AIFMESSAGELOG a
INNER JOIN AIFMESSAGELOG b
ON a.REQUESTMESSAGEID = b.MESSAGEID
WHERE b.CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000' AND b.CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000' AND a.ACTIONID = 'Insert Action'
ORDER BY A.CREATEDDATETIME DESC
```

This returns:

```
AvgTime
50
```

**Result Needed:**

```
ActionId       ActionCount  AvgTime
Insert Action  672          50
Update Action  184          25
```

My Code:

```
SELECT a.ActionId, COUNT(a.ActionId) as ActionCount, b.FinalAvg
FROM AIFMESSAGELOG a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT AVG(AvgTime) AS FinalAvg, ACTIONID
FROM
(
SELECT c.ActionID, DATEDIFF(millisecond, d.CREATEDDATETIME, c.CREATEDDATETIME)*1.0 AS AvgTime 
FROM AIFMESSAGELOG c
INNER JOIN AIFMESSAGELOG d
ON c.REQUESTMESSAGEID = d.MESSAGEID
)MyTable
) b
ON a.ACTIONID = b.ACTIONID
WHERE a.DIRECTION = 1 AND a.CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000' AND a.CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000'
Group By a.ActionId
Order By ActionCount DESC
```

I get the following error when I try to run this last query:

> Column 'MyTable.ActionID' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please do note, I have to do a `DATEDIFF` to get from 2 different rows in the same table and column. 
**My table:**

```
AIFMESSAGELOG 
-------------
ACTIONID
REQUESTMESSAGEID 
MESSAGEID
DIRECTION
CREATEDDATETIME
```

Comment: just do *AVG(b.FinalAvg) FinalAvg*

Comment: Thank you @mxix but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Add the AVG to the outer FinalAvg. Every query that has a group by, all the fields must either be in the group by OR be aggregated(SUM,MAX,AVG,...). The error pointing to the fact that b.FinalAvg is not referenced in the GROUP BY and is not being aggregated.

Comment: is aifmessagelog.requestmessageid to aifmessagelog.messageid a 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: @Matt Yes. Its tracking a web service request and response in different rows. `Direction =1` is the `Request` and `Direction =2` is the `Response`.

Comment: @mxix I replace `b.FinalAvg` with `AVG(b.FinalAvg) FinalAvg` in the first line and I still get the same error. Am I mistaken and need to put it somewhere else?

Comment: so it is an interesting challenge to try to morph someone else's code, but you will probably get better answers from us if you include some sample data and an expected result based upon that data.  Then spend some time defining the business logic.  As it stands you are asking how to mash up what we can see and that might not be the best way for you to proceed.

Comment: @Parfait got it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a join of two aggregate derived tables, joined by `ACTIONID`:

```
SELECT t1.ActionId, t1.ActionCount, t2.AvgTime

FROM    
   (SELECT ActionId, COUNT(ActionId) as ActionCount
    FROM AIFMESSAGELOG
    WHERE DIRECTION = 1 
    AND CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000' 
    AND CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000'
    GROUP By ActionId) As t1

INNER JOIN    
   (SELECT a.ACTIONID, 
           AVG(DATEDIFF(millisecond, b.CREATEDDATETIME, a.CREATEDDATETIME)*1.0) AS AvgTime
    FROM AIFMESSAGELOG a
    INNER JOIN AIFMESSAGELOG b
            ON a.REQUESTMESSAGEID = b.MESSAGEID
    WHERE b.CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000' 
    AND b.CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000'
    GROUP BY a.ACTIONID) AS t2

ON t1.ActionId = t2.ACTIONID
ORDER BY t1.ActionCount DESC
```

Comment: You lost AVG() operation

Comment: I will await OP's response as original query did not `AVG()`. See update AVG SQL.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be close. Your query is not `GROUPING` the `Action`. Its returns all 672 rows of `Action` and the `DATEDIFF` but each row has the proper `COUNT`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.ActionId
    ,SUM(CASE
                    WHEN a.DIRECTION = 1
                       AND a.CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000'
                       AND a.CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000'
                    THEN 1 END) AS ActionCount
    ,AVG(DATEDIFF(millisecond, b.CREATEDDATETIME, a.CREATEDDATETIME)*1.0) AS AvgTime 
FROM
    AIFMESSAGELOG a
    LEFT JOIN AIFMESSAGELOG b
    ON a.REQUESTMESSAGEID = b.MESSAGEID
    AND b.CREATEDDATETIME >= '2016-08-15 23:59:59.000' AND b.CREATEDDATETIME <= '2016-08-16 23:59:59.000' 
    AND a.ACTIONID = 'Insert Action'
GROUP BY
    a.ActionId
ORDER BY A.CREATEDDATETIME DESC
```

This will get you there but I am guessing that it can be simplified even more depending on how you actually are wanting to filter your date_time fileds.

The basics of it are to use conditional aggregation for the count and LEFT JOIN for the average.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Your answer was returning `1` as the `ActionCount` but it got me close enough that I could of ran this query and my `COUNT` query to match up the columns.

Comment: ahh yes you are right it would because I was counting the ActionId, it is a little counter intuative but using SUM(case when then 1 END) will be the same as the count you are looking for.  I updated the answer accordingly